# How to avoid shifts for content which is "strike out" (from tikz shapes.misc library)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, strikeout

In the following MWE, the `strike out` content is shifted horizontally and vertically. How avoid these shifts?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.misc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image-a}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \tikz \node [strike out,draw=red,line width=5pt]
  {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image-a}};%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Without having tested it: Why not using nearly the same code with the strikeout for the first image, too, but with the option `draw=none` instead of `draw=red`?

Comment: You are changing the boundary box, hence the shift. Use `strike out` with `opacity=0` in the frame without the strike.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh Still shifts

Comment: @Huang_d All the content has `opacity=0` hence is invisible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bounding box adjusts to its contents, that is why your picture jumps around. In order to keep the bounding box without figuring out how much bigger it gets from the `strike out` command, we need to draw the red line with full transparency. Just a simple `opacity=0` makes the contained node transparent as well; A way around it is to specify opacities for different aspects of the picture. There are `draw opacity`, `fill opacity` and `text opacity` (pgf manual sec. 23.2). We need `draw opacity=0` and `text opacity=1`, the latter because the `includegraphics` is inside the text part of the node. Hence on the first frame we need the code:

```
\begin{frame}
\tikz \node [draw opacity=0, text opacity=1,strike out,draw=red,line width=5pt]{
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image-a}};
\end{frame}
```